# GLM fitting, data argument and adding constants

Tags: r, glm

I'm trying to fit a GLM to some sampled data but am running into some issues.  I have attached the error message below, I'm not sure if i don't need the data = argument here or I need to make `x` into a dataframe. Also I need to add a small constant to `y` here as it may contain some 0 values if anyone knows how to do that?

```r
#simulating 200 values between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution

x = runif(200, min = 0, max = 1) 
lam = exp(0.3+5*x)
y = rpois(200, lambda = lam) 

#plot the data
plot(x, y, xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y', pch = 20)

#fit a gaussian GLM model to the data
model1 <- glm(y ~ x,
              data = x,
              family = gaussian(link="identity"))
```

error message

```r
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, data = x, 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
    'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
```

Comment: You don't need the `data` argument here because both `x` and `y` are in the global environment.  If you did `dat <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)` and specified `data=dat`, that would work.

Comment: To expand on what DaveArmstrong said, you could either do `model1 <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian(link="identity")) ` or `dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y);
model2 <- glm(y ~ x, data = dat, family = gaussian(link="identity"))` - they both give the same result

Comment: Had a feeling this might me the case. Any idea on how to add a small constant (0.1) to  each of my Ys?

Comment: `y <- y + .1` will do that or  `y = rpois(200, lambda = lam) + .1`.